# Azure Web App web.config Rewrite not working

Tags: azure, url, url-rewriting, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I use Azure Web App as a reverse proxy. When I typed URL like "www.ABC.com", it was working. If I change to "www.ABC.com/abc", it wasn't working. Then it will change my URL to the "www.ABC.com/abc". I just want to keep this URL on Azure Web App like "http://ABC.azurewebsites.net". Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

```
 <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https:/www.ABC.com/abc/{R:1}" />
        <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" value="https:/www.ABC.com/abc/{R:1}" /> 
            <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" /> 
            <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
            <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
        </serverVariables>
    </rule>
```

Comment: Do you a try to use [WebApp Reverse Proxy site extension](https://eelco.azurewebsites.net/installing-the-reverse-proxy-site-extension/) ? We can install it via azure portal. As I know  reverse proxy is off by default on the Azure WebApp.

Comment: I didn't use extension, but the web site can't show image. Because the image folder is in another directory like "www.ABC.com" not in "www.ABC.com/abc". Could I add something in the rule to get the image?

Comment: Just base on my test, it seems that Azure Web App as a reverse proxy is not working now.